# Get ID which has never belongs any category

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
ID |Location|Programs|School                                                
---+--------+--------+-------
 1 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 1 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 1 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 1 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 2 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 2 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 2 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 3 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 4 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 4 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 4 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 4 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 5 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 5 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 5 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 6 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 6 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 6 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 7 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 7 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 7 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 8 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                    
 8 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 8 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 8 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 8 |ABC     |E       | 1                                                    
 9 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                    
 9 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                    
 9 |ABC     |D       | 1                                                    
 9 |ABC     |E       | 1                                                    
10 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                   
10 |ABC     |B       | 1                                                   
10 |ABC     |C       | 1                                                   
11 |ABC     |A       | 1                                                   
11 |ABC     |B       | 1
```

I want to get the IDs 6, 7, 10, 11 any ID contains D or E will be filtered.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one table, then aggregation is easy enough:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when program in ('D', 'E') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

More likely, you have a table of ids, in which case I would recommend `not exists`:

```
select id
from ids
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.id = ids.id and t.program in ('D', 'E'));
```

This can take advantage of appropriate indexes and can be quite fast.